# Parse CSV file, check if IPs in one column are in another, output entire row if yes

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension

I have one CSV that lists IP addresses in column A and column B. I want to see if any of the IPs in column A are in column B, and if so write out the entire row to a new CSV. The way it's working now is it's comparing itself to the row next to it, instead of A 1 checking B 1,2,3,4...rows. There are many more IP addresses in column B than A, the current script is checking those too but it shouldn't as they're blank (work around noted below didn't work).

```
import csv
f = open('matching.csv', 'wb')  # Final file
writer = csv.writer(f)

with open('input', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spreadsheet = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for ip in spreadsheet:
        if ip[0] in ip[1]: #If the IPs in Column A are in Column B
       #if ip[0] in ip[1] and ip[0] != "": # This makes a blank file
            try:
                writer.writerow(ip[1:]) # Matched, write matching IP row
            except:
                print "Issue writing to new file", ip[0:2]
        else:
            print "Col A IP not in Col B ", ip[0:2]
```

Example (Col A, Col B, Col C ...):

```
10.11.11.11, 10.22.22.22, foo1
10.22.22.25,10.33.33.33, foo2
10.33.33.33, 10.44.44.44, foo3
```

Matched Output: `10.33.33.33, foo2`

Comment: Assuming you want to compare any of the IPs in column A to column B on a file-wide basis, not just column B for thet specific row, won't you need to make an extra initial pass over the entire file and store (as a set) all of column B (you could store column A instead, but storing B as a set makes much more sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `set` of the column A values then use the `in` operator to test each of the column B values.

```
import csv

# TESTED with Python2
with open('input', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spreadsheet = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

column_a = set(line[0] for line in spreadsheet)
matches = [line[1:] for line in spreadsheet if line[1] in column_a]

with open('match.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(matches)
```

Given this input:

```
2,1,George
4,2,John
6,3,Tom
8,4,Jim1
10,5,Jim2
,6,JohnQ
,7,Andy
,8,Marty
,9,Bill
```

The script identifies 2, 4, 6, and 8 as entries in column A that each match some entry in column B. It then writes the corresponding column B-Z values in a new csv.

Here is the result:

```
2,John
4,Jim1
6,JohnQ
8,Marty
```

Comment: This did execute fine, but it has values in column B that are not in column A.

Comment: @LampShade So what? Those values will never match anything in `line[0]`, so they won't produce any extra matches in the output. Are you just worried about the wasted memory for building a bigger set than needed or something?

Comment: @LampShade Or is it that there are blank values in both columns, but you don't want the rows with a blank value in column A to print out? If that's the case, just change it to `… if line[0] and line[0] in column_b`

Comment: @abarnert I'll rephrase that, I don't know why I said it like that: The resulting IPs in the final file are not in the inputs from Column A. In other words, it's putting IPs in the final file that were not in Column A for the input -- they're false results.

Comment: @LampShade - Of course there are column B entries in the final result that don't match column A.  There must be, given the requirements you specified. Each line in the final file is a line from the original file in which columnA matches some entry in columnB, not necessarily from that particular row. If I misunderstood your requirements, perhaps you could edit your question with a more precise description, perhaps including a short input file and the expected output.

Comment: @Robᵩ, my bad...clarified the question. If an IP in A matches one in B, print out everything from that specific row starting fromColumn B.

Comment: @LampShade - I have updated my answer to reflect your clarification. Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: @Robᵩ That got it! I've never seen that method in the brackets used before, what is that called?

Comment: @LampShade: that's a **list comprehension**. It's one of the most basic but powerful Python idioms, you will find it super-useful.